# join tables based on partial string match from multiple columns postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two datasets:

regional

[image: regional]

geo

[image: geo table]

The regional table contains a location column with information about cities of UK. The geo table contains multiple columns which contain location information on different levels i.e. county, local govt, regions etc. I want to join these 2 tables based on partial string match of regional table to any of the first 3 columns of geo table.
I have tried the following code but it gives null value.

```
SELECT a.created_at, a.text, SPLIT_PART(a.location, ',', 1) as location, b.*
FROM s.regional a
LEFT JOIN s.geo b
ON (a.location = b.name or a.location= b.county or a.location=b.local_govt)
```

Comment: basically the information in the location column can exist in any of the first 3 columns of 2nd table. I want to somehow know the region to which the location belongs.

Comment: Do you think any of the regionals you show *should* match any of the geos you show?  If not, then please pick some different example data.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `a.location` use `SPLIT_PART(a.location, ',', 1)` in the `ON` clause:

```
ON SPLIT_PART(a.location, ',', 1) IN (b.name, b.county, b.local_govt)
```